# que tipo tengo que poner en MySQL para que salgan dos valores

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: donde extraigo los datos][image: dando el valor]estoy extrayendo datos de una pagina web y guardandolo en mi base de datos (MySQL) pero tengo un problema, tengo un dato que es 40:20, es decir son dos numeros separados con dos puntos y nose como tengo que poner el  tipo (DECIMAL o FLOAT) para que despues cuando lo quiera ver en internet me aparezca bien. He puesto como TIPO: FLOAT y LONGITUD: 4,2 y me sale 40.00 tambien he puesto DECIMAL con el mismo valor y me el resultado es el mismo. ¿Alguien me podria ayudar en poner el valor y la longitud? [image: donde aparece la flecha]

Comment: En la imagen que enlazas, en ningun sitio se ve que haya un dato separado por `:`. De todas maneras, no te sirve un `varchar`?

Comment: Hola @Pikoh si, la imagen es el resultado que me da, cuando extraigo los datos en la pagina web de donde los extraigo aparecen con los dos puntos, pero mi cuestion es si es posible que en vez de salir el 00 me salga por ejemplo un 20 o otro numero. Poniendo con VARCHAR me salia solo el primer numero, es decir solo el 60. Ponia VARCHAR y como valor 10

Comment: El problema es que tu pregunta es bastante vaga. Para poder ayudarte, haría falta ver que código usas para guardar los datos,un ejemplo de los datos recibidos, y el código que usas para mostrarlo. Intenta crear un [mcve] y será mas fácil que alguien pueda ayudarte :)

Comment: Siempre `DECIMAL` es la mejor opción para este tipo de datos. `DOUBLE`  y `FLOAT` suelen dar problemas con el redondeo de valores por ejemplo. Pero el hecho de que no te reconozca el valor decimal `.20` es debido al separador `:`. Cuando tomas los datos deberías hacer un `REPLACE` que cambie los dos puntos por un punto, de forma que el valor quede así: `40.20`, entonces quedará bien insertado en tu columna decimal. El insert debería quedar así para que se haga bien: **`INSERT INTO tu_tabla (tu_columna_decimal) VALUES(40.20);`**

Comment: Por ejemplo una consulta de inserción que tomase el dato original y lo preparase para ser un `DECIMAL` en toda regla sería: **`INSERT INTO tu_tabla (tu_columna_decimal) VALUES (REPLACE '40:20',':','.');`** El resultado del replace será `'40.20'`. Me parece que en este caso no necesitaría convertir la cadena a `DECIMAL`, no lo he probado. Si da problemas entonces habría que convertirla con `CAST`.

Comment: Hola @pikoh te he puesto mas fotos... espero que asi se entienda mejor

Comment: Imanol, haz caso a @A.Cedano que es un experto en php. No es mi campo :)

Comment: Imanol si tienes acceso a modificar la tabla dímelo y te propondré una solución bastante fácil a tu problema.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano ¿y para ello deberia de ir haciendo eso uno por uno? quiero decir, tengo mas de una tabla con esos datos ya que es una tabla de futbol y la cosa es que ese valor es de los goles a favor y en contra

Comment: ¿acceso a MySQL dices? @A.Cedano

Comment: Me refiero a si tienes privilegios para **crear una nueva columna en la tabla**. Te mostraré una solución en la que creas una nueva columna del tipo `DECIMAL`  y pasas a ella de forma automática con una sola consulta cada dato en su fila respectiva. Ahora te muestro a lo que me refiero.

Comment: Por cierto Imanol...está separado por `:` probablemente porque no es un decimal, sino dos numeros separados. Entiendo que en esa estadística el primer numero son los goles a favor, y el segundo los goles en contra

Comment: si, si que tengo privilegio para crear una columna @A.Cedano

Comment: @Pikoh buen punto ese... no lo había pensado. Imanol, ¿eso no representará lo que dice Pikoh, o sea, los goles a favor y en contra? ¿O eso es un dato `DECIMAL` en sí mismo? En caso de ser lo primero, lo que habría que hacer sería dos columnas del tipo `INT`, una para los goles a favor y otra para los goles en contra. Confirma ese dato por favor.

Comment: si, es lo que ha dicho los goles a favor y en contra @A.Cedano

Comment: Entonces lo correcto sería separar esa columna en dos columnas, no convertirla a `DECIMAL`.  De todos modos, ya que estoy elaborando la respuesta, te mostraré las dos posibilidades. Ahora vuelvo...

Comment: muchas gracias por tu interes @A.Cedano :)

Answer (score 2):

Te mostraré un ejemplo de solución.

En este caso lo correcto sería tener dos columnas del tipo `INT` que almacenen los goles a favor y en contra. Si por algún motivo se quieren representar así: `40:20`, eso se puede hacer en la salida. En BD conviene guardar cada dato como una entidad propia y con el tipo de dato propio. No cometas nunca el error de guardar un dato numérico o de fecha como `VARCHAR`. Tendrás problemas a la larga para mantener los datos y para presentarlos.

Supongamos que te piden el total de goles a favor por separado, o el total de goles a favor global, o el total de goles en el año 2014, o el total de goles en contra cuando se jugó con el equipo X. Será harto difícil calcular esos datos si tú tienes en una columna `VARCHAR` dos datos en uno. Es más, puede que hasta ocupe más espacio en la BD que teniendo dos `INT`...

Entonces para resolver esto, habría que:

- crear dos nuevas columnas del tipo `INT`. En el ejemplo las he llamado `a_favor` y `en_contra`.
- hacer una consulta que obtenga por un lado los valores que están antes de `:` y por otro lado los que están después de `:`, y asigne esos valores a las columnas citadas anteriormente.

Esta consulta sería algo así:

```
UPDATE validar_goles SET 
     a_favor= SUBSTRING_INDEX( goals , ':', 1 ),
     en_contra= SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( goals , ':', 2 ),':',-1) ;
```

### NO hagas esto

Esto ya no hay que aplicarlo, pero lo pongo aquí por si te hiciera falta alguna vez para otro caso que sí lo amerite.

Si se quisiera validar el dato de la columna `goles` a un dato **realmente** `DECIMAL`, se podría hacer creando una nueva columna, que he llamado `decimal_goals`, unir la tabla consigo misma reemplazando los dos puntos de la columna `goals` por un `punto`, e insertando ese valor en la nueva columna decimal. Lo que hará el `REPLACE` será crear un dato convertible (parseable) a `DECIMAL` que te permitirá registrar los valores correctamente en tu nueva columna del tipo `DECIMAL`.

La consulta quedaría así:

```
 UPDATE validar_goles AS t2
    LEFT JOIN validar_goles AS t1 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
    SET t1.decimal_goals = REPLACE(t2.goals,':','.');
```

### NOTAS:

> 1. Estas consultas actualizarían toda la tabla con una sola ejecución, no habría que ejecutarlas por cada fila.
> 2. Por tanto, conviene siempre antes de realizar estos cambios **hacer una copia de seguridad de la tabla**.
> 3. Es posible que si la actual columna `GOALS` de tu tabla es `VARCHAR` algunos valores estén ingresados mal. Este es otro de los problemas añadidos cuando empleamos tipos de datos que no son los adecuados. Puede que haya valores con espacios en blanco, con caracteres cualesquiera que no sean números ni los dos puntos. De todos modos, la consulta podría fallar en esos valores y deberás corregirlos. Para la cuestión de los espacios en blanco puedes limpiar la columna con funciones adecuadas como [`TRIM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) .

---

### Demo

He aquí una prueba de concepto:

<kbd>[**VER DEMO EN REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/JEM42303)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS validar_goles 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    goals VARCHAR(10),
    decimal_goals DECIMAL(10,2),
    a_favor INT,
    en_contra INT
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO validar_goles (goals)
    VALUES 
        ('50:14'),
        ('41:22'),
        ('30:26')
;

SELECT * FROM validar_goles;

UPDATE validar_goles SET 
     a_favor= SUBSTRING_INDEX( goals , ':', 1 ),
     en_contra= SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( goals , ':', 2 ),':',-1) ;

UPDATE validar_goles AS t2
LEFT JOIN validar_goles AS t1 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
SET t1.decimal_goals = REPLACE(t2.goals,':','.');
   
SELECT * FROM validar_goles;
```

**Resultado:**

Esta es la tabla antes de los cambios:

```
ID  goals   decimal_goals   a_favor     en_contra
1   50:14   NULL             NULL        NULL
2   41:22   NULL             NULL        NULL
3   30:26   NULL             NULL        NULL
```

Y después de los cambios:

```
ID  goals   decimal_goals   a_favor      en_contra
1   50:14   50,14            50          14
2   41:22   41,22            41          22
3   30:26   30,26            30          26
```

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedado hare la prueba haber quetal sale!! de verdad que gracias por tu interes :)

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que la mejor solución sería tratar ese dato como varchar, y en el caso que necesites mostrar o tratar los números por separado, cuando lo recojas de nuevo en la web, dividirlo con la funcion [split()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.split.php)

Y en el caso de que no necesites tratar los números por separado lo mostraría sin más como varchar y no complicaría la funcionalidad inecesariamente.

Un saludo espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: La cosa es que cuando pongo como VARCHAR no me salen los dos numeros, solo me sale el primero... @Domingo carrasco bueno

Comment: utiliza VARCHAR2 para base de datos mysql, debería de funcionar.

Comment: VARCHAR 2 dices que ponga en la columna valor un 2 verdad? @Domingo carrasco bueno